# Fitting a cross sectional surface profile to a generalized known formula to obtain coefficients and mathematically model the surface

Tags: matlab, python-2.7, curve-fitting, coefficients

I designed an optical system with an a-spheric surface profile. I then had this lens manufactured and measured. I was given a cross sectional graph from the measurement of the manufactured surface profile. (The surface holds rotational symmetry)

The formula being used to model said aspheric surface is:
[image: Formula used to model aspheric surfaces with explanation of terms]

How can I fit this generalized equation with my cross sectional curve to obtain corresponding `alpha` coefficients to the curve? (`alpha` coefficients are referring to those in the provided formula) *I know the radius of curvature of the surface.*

I have access to Python and Matlab (no toolboxes) to achieve this. I can also obtain digitized, tabulated data points from the curve.

Comment: This question might be a candidate for this SE site:  http://math.stackexchange.com/

If you are asking specifically about programming this in Python or Matlab, then StackOverflow asks that you also provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us what you have tried so far and how to help you better.

Comment: Though your question is unclear, I think you can use MATLAB's `lsqcurvefit` to do this. Read [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/examples/nonlinear-data-fitting.html) for more information. If you don't have MATLAB's optimization toolbox, the use [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). You just have to write your function in symbolic form. Examples can be found on the pages I have linked.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a array of discreet *r* and for each value of this array *z(r)*. You want to fit a curve to estimate the parameters of an aspheric lens. I will use `lmfit` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340477) to show one way to do this using python.

Importing the modules used for this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model, Parameters
```

Define the function of an asperic lens:

```
def asphere_complete(x, r0, k, a2, a4, a6, a8, a10, a12):
    r_squared = x ** 2.
    z_even_r = r_squared * (a2 + (r_squared * (a4 + r_squared * (a6 + r_squared * (a8 + r_squared * (a10 + (r_squared * a12)))))))

    square_root_term = 1 - (1 + k) * ((x / r0) ** 2)
    zg = (x ** 2) / (r0 * (1 + np.sqrt(square_root_term)))
    return z_even_r + zg
```

As you do not provide any data, I will use the following to create some example data, including artificial noise:

```
def generate_dummy_data(x, asphere_parameters, noise_sigma, seed=12345):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    return asphere_complete(x, **asphere_parameters) + noise_sigma * np.random.randn(x.shape[0])
```

The following function does the fitting and plots the resulting curve:

```
def fit_asphere(r, z, fit_parameters):
    # create two subplots to plot the original data and the fit in one plot and the residual in another
    fig, axarr = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
    fit_plot = axarr[0]
    residuum_plot = axarr[1]

    # configure first plot:
    fit_plot.set_xlabel("r")
    fit_plot.set_ylabel("z")
    fit_plot.grid()

    # configure second plot:
    residuum_plot.set_xlabel("r")
    residuum_plot.set_ylabel("$\Delta$z")
    residuum_plot.grid()

    # plot original data
    fit_plot.plot(r, z, label="Input")

    # create an lmfit model and the parameters
    function_model = Model(asphere_complete)

    # The fitting procedure may throw ValueErrors, if the radicand gets negative
    try:
        result = function_model.fit(z, fit_parameters, x=r)

        # To plot the resulting curve remove the parameters which were just used for the constraints
        opt_parameters = dict(result.values)
        opt_parameters.pop('r_max', None)
        opt_parameters.pop('radicand', None)

        # calculate z-values of fitted curve:
        z_fitted = asphere_complete(r, **opt_parameters)

        # calculate residual values
        z_residual = z - z_fitted

        # plot fit and residual:
        fit_plot.plot(r, z_fitted, label="Fit")
        residuum_plot.plot(r, z_residual, label="Residual")

        # legends:
        fit_plot.legend(loc="best")
        residuum_plot.legend(loc="best")

        print(result.fit_report())
    except ValueError as val_error:
        print("Fit Failed: ")
        print(val_error)
```

To set the parameters of the example data I use the `Parameters`object of `lmfit`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parameters_dummy = Parameters()
    parameters_dummy.add('r0', value=-34.4)
    parameters_dummy.add('k', value=-0.98)
    parameters_dummy.add('a2', value=0)
    parameters_dummy.add('a4', value=-9.67e-9)
    parameters_dummy.add('a6', value=1.59e-10)
    parameters_dummy.add('a8', value=-5.0e-12)
    parameters_dummy.add('a10', value=0)
    parameters_dummy.add('a12', value=-1.0e-19)
```

Create the example data:

```
r = np.linspace(0, 35, 1000)
z = generate_dummy_data(r, parameters_dummy, 0.00001)
```

The reason to use `lmfit`instead of `scipy`'s `curve_fit`is that the radicand of the square root may become negativ. We need to ensure:

[image]

Therefor, we need to define a constraint as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340477). 
Let's start to define our parameters we want to use in fitting. The basic radius is added straightforward:

```
parameters = Parameters()
parameters.add('r0', value=-30, vary=True)
```

To obey the inequality add a variable `radicand` which is not allowed to become less than zero. Instead of letting `k` taking part in the fitting normaly, make it direclty dependend on `r0`, `r_max` and `radicand`. We need to use `r_max` because the inequality is most problematic for the maximal *r*. Solving the inequalty for `k` leads to

[image]

which is used as `expr`below. I use a bool flag to switch on/off the constraint:

```
keep_radicand_safe = True
if keep_radicand_safe:
    r_max = np.max(r)
    parameters.add('r_max', r_max, vary=False)
    parameters.add('radicand', value=0.98, vary=True, min=0)
    parameters.add('k', expr='(r0/r_max)**2*(1-radicand)-1')
else:
    parameters.add('k', value=-0.98, vary=True)
```

The remaining parameters are added straightforward:

```
parameters.add('a2', value=0, vary=False)
parameters.add('a4', value=0, vary=True)
parameters.add('a6', value=0, vary=True)
parameters.add('a8', value=0, vary=True)
parameters.add('a10', value=0, vary=False)
parameters.add('a12', value=0, vary=True)
```

Now we are ready to start and get our results:

```
fit_asphere(r, z, parameters)
plt.show()
```

On the console you should see the output:

```
[[Variables]]
    r0:       -34.3999435 +/- 6.1027e-05 (0.00%) (init = -30)
    r_max:     35 (fixed)
    radicand:  0.71508611 +/- 0.09385813 (13.13%) (init = 0.98)
    k:        -0.72477176 +/- 0.09066656 (12.51%) == '(r0/r_max)**2*(1-radicand)-1'
    a2:        0 (fixed)
    a4:        7.7436e-07 +/- 2.7872e-07 (35.99%) (init = 0)
    a6:        2.5547e-10 +/- 6.3330e-11 (24.79%) (init = 0)
    a8:       -4.9832e-12 +/- 1.7115e-14 (0.34%) (init = 0)
    a10:       0 (fixed)
    a12:      -9.8670e-20 +/- 2.0716e-21 (2.10%) (init = 0)
```

With the data I use above, you should see the fit fail if `keep_radicand_safe` is set to `False`.